# random number selection probability

Tags: python, random

I know how to choose random numbers using the Python `random` library.

This will choose 5 random numbers between 0 and 20:

```
import random

for x in range(5):
    print random.randint(0,20)
```

I would like to select one number between 0 and 20, e.g. 10, and after that find the probability of the upcoming 5 numbers.

Comment: The probability would always be the same as they're mutually exclusive

Comment: right Tubs. but I try to find the upcoming 5 number. any other option

Comment: As @Tubs explained, The probability of each upcoming upcoming number is 1/20 in your case, because your pool of numbers is 20. That will be the same for any X upcoming numbers.

Comment: What is your definition of the probability "of a number" or "of the upcoming numbers"?

Comment: hi @mkrieger1..  I try to find out the possibility of 5 number after selection of any random number.

Answer (score 1):

If you select a random number in range 0 to 20, the probability for each value in the range will always be 5% (if the range includes both 0 and 20, then the probability is going to be 100/21 ≈ 4.75%). It does not depend on any previous or next values.

Comment: I try to find out the possibility of 5 number after selection of any random number.

Comment: I don't follow. Could you perhaps give me an example?

Comment: If the probability of each number isn't 5% regardless of what came before, then they're not random. And Python uses a good random number generator.